# Braintree Paypal.Authorize() doesn't work

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

Here is the code

```
public void payWithPayPal(View v) throws InvalidArgumentException {
    try {
                BraintreeFragment fragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(this,
                        "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");

                PayPal.authorizeAccount
                        (fragment);
            } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

I'm using test client token obtained during the following the implementation guide. Nothing happens when above code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so the problem was that i had underscore in my package name and removing that fixed the issue. Indeed this was documented but in my opinion a weird requirement. Here is the [link](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/android/v2#browser-switch-setup) to the documentation.

> IMPORTANT Your app's URL scheme must begin with your app's package ID
>   and end with .braintree. For example, if the Package ID is
>   com.your-company.your-app, then your URL scheme should be
>   com.your-company.your-app.braintree. ${applicationId} is automatically
>   applied with your app's package when using Gradle.
>
> Note: The scheme you define must use all lowercase letters. If your
>   package contains underscores, the underscores should be removed when
>   specifying the scheme in your Android Manifest.